# Transform a df into a specific object structure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df which I am getting from a table

```
ID    CAT     SUB_CAT    KEY     VALUE
=============================================
1     AA        AA_1      X        10
2     AA        AA_1      Y        20
3     AA        AA_1      Z        15
```

Previously I was using the **df.to_dict('records')** and converting them to a list, then I was able to return it from my API call as a JSON object.

Now in a scenario, the values for CAT and SUB_CAT will always be the same. so I was thinking to convert the df into something like

```
{
   "CAT": "AA",
   "SUB_CAT": "AA_1",
   "METRICS": [
       {
          "ID": 1,
          "KEY": "X",
          "VALUE": 10
       },
       {
          "ID": 2,
          "KEY": "Y",
          "VALUE": 20
       },
       {
          "ID": 3,
          "KEY": "Z",
          "VALUE": 15
       }
          
    ]
}
```

Can someone help me transform the df into the above JSON format or let me know how should I proceed please.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lambda function in [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
d = (df.groupby(['CAT','SUB_CAT'])[['ID','KEY','VALUE']]
       .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('records'))
       .reset_index(name='METRICS')
       .to_dict('records'))
print (d)


[
   {
      "CAT":"AA",
      "SUB_CAT":"AA_1",
      "METRICS":[
         {
            "ID":1,
            "KEY":"X",
            "VALUE":10
         },
         {
            "ID":2,
            "KEY":"Y",
            "VALUE":20
         },
         {
            "ID":3,
            "KEY":"Z",
            "VALUE":15
         }
      ]
   }
]
```